# How to truncate to a specific number of decimals in VB6?

Tags: vb6, truncate

How do I truncate a number to a specific number of decimal places in VB6?

Comment: Look at Format with a custom format string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with Complise above: if the goal is to truncate, Fix is a better choice than Int

```
Function TrimDigits(val As Double, Optional numdig As Integer = 2) As Double
Try
    Return Fix(val * 10 ^ numdig) / 10 ^ numdig
Catch ex As Exception
    Return 0
End Try
```

End Function

Answer (score 4):

```
truncatedNumber = Fix ( originalNumber * 100 ) / 100 'Truncate to 2 decimals.
truncatedNumber = Fix ( originalNumber * 1000 ) / 1000 'Truncate to 3 decimals.
truncatedNumber = Fix ( originalNumber * 10000 ) / 10000 'Truncate to 4 decimals.
```

Fix() returns the integer portion of a number.

Example 01: Truncate 3.1415 to 2 decimals.

- 3.1415 x 100 equals 314.15
- Fix(314.15) returns 314
- 314 / 100 equals 3.14

Example 02: Truncate 3.1415 to 3 decimals.

- 3.1415 x 1000 equals 3141.5
- Fix(3141.5) returns 3141
- 3141 / 1000 equals 3.141

Edit:
As noted by Complise and Bruno, Int does not truncate negative numbers correctly. Int converts -8.4 to -9, and Fix converts -8.4 to -8. So Fix is the way to go.

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.

Comment: Added a few words of explanation, as requested by @Thom :-)

Answer (score 1):

i would use fix() instead of int(), in order not to change in negative numbers and no to round then as in format()

? int(-8.666*100)/100 , fix(-8.666*100)/100

-8.67             -8.66

Answer (score -2):

I would use Format:

```
Dim d as Double
d = CDbl(Format("123.22323263",".0000"))
```

Comment: Format doesn't truncate, rather it rounds up.